# ubercart abandoned orders marked as completed in civicrm

Tags: drupal-7, ubercart, civicrm

I'm using drupal(7.38), civicrm(4.6.5), ubercart(7.x-3.8) and ubercart_civicrm(7.x-4.x-dev). Whenever a user(registered/anonymous) is purchase a product from the site, a contribution will be added into the civcrm user. If the user is anonymous, system will create the user by using email both in drupal as well as civicrm also. I notice some of the products status is 'Abandoned' in ubercart, but under the corresponding user contribution tab, the product is listing as Completed. I gone throw the uc_civicrm module at last I found some piece of codes in uc_civicrm/uc_civicrm.module

```
function _uc_civicrm_map_contribution_status($order_status) {
  // NOTE: There may be a more "correct" way to do this.
  $map = array(
    "completed"        => 1,
    "payment_received" => 1,
    "pending"          => 2,
    "processing"       => 5,
    "canceled"         => 3,
    "in_checkout"      => 5,
  );

  if (array_key_exists($order_status, $map)) {
    $id = $map[$order_status];
  }
  else {
    // Oh no.
    $id = 1;
    watchdog('uc_civicrm', 'There is no status that maps to %order_status, marking as "Complete"', array('%order_status' => $order_status), WATCHDOG_WARNING);
  }

  return $id;
}
```

I want to synchronize ubercart order status with civicrm contributions status. Please help me out this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

If you want to map 'abandoned' to the 'canceled' status in CiviCRM (there is no "abandoned" status in CiviCRM) you could revise the above like so:

```
$map = array(
 "completed"        => 1,
 "payment_received" => 1,
 "pending"          => 2,
 "processing"       => 5,
 "canceled"         => 3,
 "abandoned"         => 3,
 "in_checkout"      => 5,
);
```

Then I'd recommend making a bug report/patch [on the issue you filed at the project page](https://www.drupal.org/node/2606644) so it gets into the module core if the maintainers agree.

Comment: Hey @laryn, Thanks for your suggestion. This could be the easiest and best solution for now.

Comment: No problem. PS. did you know of the CiviCRM specific StackExchange? http://civicrm.stackexchange.com

Comment: yes I know. I have posted the question there as well.

Answer (score 0):

On the one site where we had CiviCRM and Ubercart well (it was Drupal 6) we ended up needing to use both
- [UC CiviCRM](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_civicrm), 
- [Ubercart CiviCRM Products](https://www.drupal.org/project/uc_civicrm_product)
but I see the latter only was released for D6

More recently for Commerce integration we have switched from using the module to using [CiviCRM Entity](https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity) and [Drupal Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules).

Not sure how much the above helps but thought I should mention it.

Comment: Thanks for replay. I will try the your suggestion and I will let know